# how to use explode?

Tags: php, arrays, cookies, explode

So i have this php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["currentsearchctrl"])) {
    $cookz = $_COOKIE["currentsearchctrl"];
    $data = explode(';', $cookz, -1);
    $newdata = array();

    foreach($data as $value){
        $newdata[] = explode(':', $value, -1);
    }    
    print_r($newdata);

} else { }
?>
```

The cookie that is being read by php:

> %20Rod%20Stewart%20%3A%2059088763306%3B%20Led%20Zeppelin%20Official%20%3A%20131572223581891%3B%20Lynyrd%20Skynyrd%20%3A%206983887641%3B%20Black%20Sabbath%20%3A%2056848544614%3B

but the 'print_r' is outputting:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => Rod Stewart ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Led Zeppelin Official ) [2] => Array ( [0] => Lynyrd Skynyrd ) [3] => Array ( [0] => Black Sabbath ) )
```

The 'id' is missing. I needed it to be. Array([0] => Array ([0] => Rod Stewart, [1] => 1200420 ) [1] => Array ( [0] => Led Zeppelin Official, [1] => 110024294 )...

To help, this is the output of print_r($data):

```
Array ( [0] => Rod Stewart : 59088763306 [1] => Led Zeppelin Official : 131572223581891 [2] => Lynyrd Skynyrd : 6983887641 [3] => Black Sabbath : 56848544614 )
```

Could someone help?

Comment: I don't see a `1200420` in your raw cookie text, nor a `110024294`?

Comment: ...of course, that was an example. the true value of the cookie is in $data: Array ( [0] => Rod Stewart : 59088763306 [1] => Led Zeppelin Official : 131572223581891 [2] => Lynyrd Skynyrd : 6983887641 [3] => Black Sabbath : 56848544614 ) ----- as you see, the values of the ':' i need to put them in a separate object of the array that is being created as '$newdata'

Comment: Ah well, you said "I need it to be" and then include values that aren't present, hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try with regular expressions?

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE["currentsearchctrl"])) {
    $cookz = urldecode($_COOKIE["currentsearchctrl"]);
    preg_match_all("#(?P<artist>(?:\w|\s)+)\s:\s(?P<id>\d+)#", $cookz, $matchs, PREG_SET_ORDER);    
    print_r($matchs);
} else { }
?>
```

EDIT: Sorry I didn't notice the name wasn't complete

Example: [preg_match_all](http://xrg.es/?410573745)

Comment: @HadriandeOliveira did you look at the link I added? It has the example you provided with the result you want

Comment: @HadriandeOliveira I saw the other answer.. I edited my answer because I didn't saw the name wasn't complete.. you can use whatever solution you prefer though :)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
$data = array (0 => "Rod Stewart : 59088763306", 1 => "Led Zeppelin Official : 131572223581891", 2 => "Lynyrd Skynyrd : 6983887641", 3 => "Black Sabbath : 56848544614" );


$data = array_map(function($item){
    list($artist, $id) = explode(' : ', $item);
    return array('id'=>$id, 'artist'=>$artist);
}, $data);

print_r($data);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59088763306
            [artist] => Rod Stewart
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 131572223581891
            [artist] => Led Zeppelin Official
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 6983887641
            [artist] => Lynyrd Skynyrd
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 56848544614
            [artist] => Black Sabbath
        )

)
```

Comment: exactly. but SeRPRo got it above. im gonna use the values to build some <div>'s.

Comment: wait, but this get's it better because it outputs the whole name.

Comment: there's something wrong. it's returning: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')'

Answer (score 0):

use serialize() and unserialize()

```
$data = serialize($cookz);
```

Serializing string ensures that you store exact structire into the string to be later recovered.

Comment: When you store value to the cookie, use `$string=serialize($array)`, when you are retrieving the array, use `$array=unserialize($string)`.

Comment: the $data part is good. the problem is that i want to 'explode' the values of the array created to 2 new arrays in each '$newdata'. have the '0' object = the name and the '1' object = the id.

Comment: OK, I just suggested how thing should be propperly done. If it is not too time expensive, redesign it :)

Comment: Well, let me tell you the story. There is another page with some objects, and when i click on them jquery appends they're name and id to the cookie. And when i tried to serialize the value it gave an error, because i was trying to put an array in form of text inside the cookie then trying to make an array in php, messy stuff. then i saw the 'explode' way. and in one way, it could help because i could do a htmlentities on the values, and so on.